# Generate shortest bit sequence base -2

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Given an integer X where X can be negative or positive. find the shortest bit sequence that represent X in a base -2 system.

In a base -2 system, given an array A of N bits, the represented integer is: sum of A[i]*(-2 power i) for i = 0..N-1

example:

```
[1,0,1] = 5
[1,0,0,1] = -7
[1,0,0,1,0,1] = -39
```

so, given X = 18 the algorithm should return [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

any idea on how to implement such an algorithm.. such that, given an integer X it returns the shortest bit sequence that represent that integer ?

The only thing that I came up with is brute force search.. starting at bit 0 and calculating all possible sums until one of the sums is equal to X.. which does not look nice!

Comment: Should not you solve your homework/competition by yourself?

Comment: @SalvadorDali who told you it is a homework?

Comment: Seems to me you are asking what the binary representation of an integer is? In that case "shortest bit sequence" doesn't make sense, there is one and only one bit sequence for each number.

Comment: In principle, there's nothing wrong with asking homework-related questions here. But this post doesn't seem to actually contain a question; ctrl-f for "?" returns 0 hits. Please clarify - what is your question?

Comment: @Svea I'm not sure if the solution is unique for every integer.. since we are using base-2 and not base2..

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the hint, I updated the question

Comment: @Johny Your question looks very well-defined - this is a sign that you are asking this question to learn (homework? competition? just improving your programming skills?). In this case, you should include your attempts, so people understand *where you got stuck*, and also to ensure *you actually learn something*. Do you expect someone to solve your theoretical problem for you? I hope you don't, but it looks like it. Rephrase your question so it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Johny Can this be solved for any given `X`? Or does it only cover a certain range?

Comment: @Johny who told me that it is not? You dumped your requirement which looks really close to a homework problem to me. You have not tried to solve anything by yourself and just posted it for others to solve for you.

Comment: Negabinary representation is also unique, so that's nice. Also, there's a conversion algorithm on wikipedia.

Comment: @harold thank you alot! this wiki document is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full solution, but it will probably give a good idea on how to proceed.

Suppose your base-negative-2 representation contains at most N numbers. What would be the range of numbers it represents?

A few examples:

- length 0 or less: 0
- length 1 or less: 0 ... 1
- length 2 or less: -2 ... 1
- length 3 or less: -2 ... 5
- length 4 or less: -10 ... 5

You probably can notice the recursive rule that determines the above; something like this:

> Extend the range by adding or subtracting 2<sup>n-1</sup> to the appropriate end of the earlier range

You don't even need a "closed" (in a mathematical sense) formula for this, just a recursive implementation. Extend the range until your target numbers falls inside; then generate your representation.

BTW it's also described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base).

Comment: +1 for the Wikipedia link - the [Calculation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#Calculation) is especially helpful.